# How to replace entries in a column in r

Tags: r

I'm brand new to r, and coding, and am playing around with a dataset. I have what I think should be a really straight-forward problem, but I can't figure it out, and haven't found any other code that will work.

I have a tibble with several columns. In column "RelationshipTypeCd" there are some values of "PT." I would like to change all of these to "PT" (essentially removing the period).

[image: tibble]

I am working in R studio, and have loaded the tidyverse.

Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't look like a Tibble, it looks like a screenshot from a spreadsheet program. You are likely to get better help if you post the code that generates either the Tibble in question or a Tibble that your answerers can use to prove that their answer works.

Comment: You are right, it is indeed a screenshot from Excel. However, some of the data in the tibble I do not want to post online, so uploaded this to show how the tibble was organized.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sub` here:

```r
dt$RelationshipTypeCd <- sub("^PT\\.$", "PT", dt$RelationshipTypeCd, fixed=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dt$RelationshipTypeCd <- ifelse(stringr::str_detect(dt$RelationshipTypeCd, 'PT'), 'PT', dt$RelationshipTypeCd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies.

I eventually found a solution:

```
tibble %>% 
  mutate(RelationshipTypeCd = replace(RelationshipTypeCd, RelationshipTypeCd == "PT.", "PT"))
```

I'm not really sure I understand all the arguments there, however. It appears to be using replace inside of mutate, and I don't know why the column "RelationshipTypeCd" is listed twice in the arguments for replace.